# Cannot access to a local git repository on a shared partition from my two different OS

Tags: git, zsh, ubuntu-20.04, wsl-2, windows-11

I'm working on a dual-boot machine (Ubuntu 20 and Windows 11).
All my files such as *Documents*, *Download*, etc are stored on a shared partition mounted on both OS.

Among the others, I have a *Development* folder in which I put all my local projects. All of them are using git.

Here is the issue:

I've cloned most of those projects with Ubuntu and everything is working fine.
But when I want to work on those from my Windows 11 (using WSL2), my terminal freezes immediately when I `cd` into my project folder.

My shell (`zsh` with `oh-my-zsh` and `powerlevel10k` plugings) doens't respond. And the placeholder which is suppose to show the git status of my project (amount of commits, changes, unstaged files, branch name, etc) is just stuck displaying `loading`.

The only option to get out of this is by killing the terminal.
My current workaround is to have to copies of each of my project: one cloned from Ubuntu and the other one from WSL, which isn't very handy.

Any solution or any explanation about what the problem could be?
I'm actually not sure which one of these cause the issue: git or zsh.

Comment: How do you connect your Ubuntu machine to WSL2?

Comment: It's not a good idea to directly share a repository across OSes. The data that go into a Git index are OS-dependent. (This shouldn't cause a hang, but it's still not a good idea.) Just have separate clones.

Comment: @fredrik There are not really connected, they are just mapped on the same drive. WSL2 is mapped on my Windows 11 drive which I mapped on my SharedPartition drive. Ubuntu is also mapped on that same SharedPartition drive.

Comment: @torek That's what I thought would happen. So in the end, I have to clone my repositories twice, which is what I wanted to avoid... Anyway, thank you for your answer.